# PrettyPrint HTML file and write the output in an other

Tags: html, pretty-print

Hi I am trying to read one index.html file and want (prettyprinted) output in an other file. Please help  I am using python

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest BeautifulSoup4, which you can install via `pip install bs4`

Then, it's as simple as this

```
print(BeautifulSoup(open("path/to/file/filename.html").read()).prettify())
```

Depending how you're using it, you may what to break that up into a few more lines.